# How do I pass in the SignatureOption to the FedEx RateRequest API?

Tags: api, fedex

For some deliveries I require a signature which is an extra charge. I would like to know what that extra charge is, using the rate request API. I'd like to know if this is the place to get that value or if there is some other way.

In the documentation, I only see the SignatureOption element in the explanation for the RateReplyDetails, but nothing for how to send it to them in the RateRequest.  The replies always say "SERVICE_DEFAULT" for the SignatureOption with a value of zero.  I would like the reply to come back with, for example, INDIRECT and some dollar amount.  Other options for this are ADULT, DIRECT, NO_SIGNATURE_REQUIRED, etc.

Below you can see where I tried putting the element under the RequestedShipment element.  But that causes the reply to be an "invalid element" error.  I tried it in various places in the RateRequest to no avail.

```
<ns:RateRequest xmlns:ns="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v7" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
                    <ns:UserCredential>
                        <ns:Key>00000</ns:Key>
                        <ns:Password>00000</ns:Password>
                    </ns:UserCredential>
                </ns:WebAuthenticationDetail>
                <ns:ClientDetail>
                    <ns:AccountNumber>00000</ns:AccountNumber>
                    <ns:MeterNumber>00000</ns:MeterNumber>
                </ns:ClientDetail>
                <ns:Version>
                    <ns:ServiceId>crs</ns:ServiceId>
                    <ns:Major>7</ns:Major>
                    <ns:Intermediate>0</ns:Intermediate>
                    <ns:Minor>0</ns:Minor>
                </ns:Version>
                <ns:RequestedShipment>
                    <ns:SignatureOption>INDIRECT</ns:SignatureOption>
                    <ns:ShipTimestamp>#DateFormat(Now(),'yyyy-mm-dd')#T#TimeFormat(Now(),'hh:mm:ss')#</ns:ShipTimestamp>
                    <ns:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</ns:DropoffType>
                    <ns:PackagingType>YOUR_PACKAGING</ns:PackagingType>
```

Answer (score 7):

When using more recent versions of the API you need to set the option inside of RequestedPackageLineItems. Only send the element when you've got an actual signature option selection.

```
<RequestedPackageLineItems>
… dim, weight, etc…
<SpecialServicesRequested>
<SpecialServiceTypes>SIGNATURE_OPTION</SpecialServiceTypes>
<SignatureOptionDetail>
<OptionType>DIRECT|INDIRECT|ADULT|NO_SIGNATURE_REQUIRED</OptionType>
</SignatureOptionDetail>
</SpecialServicesRequested>
</RequestedPackageLineItems>
```

Comment: The `SIGNATURE_OPTION` placement is still relevant in 2021 within the `RequestedPackageLineItems` structure!

Answer (score 1):

While adnyknas answer is correct, regarding the place you should put it in your XML, please note that the Signature service request only works in the USA:

This is info I got from FedEX tech support:

> Signature Require (SR) services are unavailable in most countries. It is for FedEx Express U.S. package services and FedEx Ground U.S. services only in U.S.A. Refer to below restriction from http://www.fedex.com/us/2014rates/surcharges-and-fees.html